# Splitting a face

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I am doing [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFLtCi6yWnA). At about 12:00 min CGGeek selects a face and first separates that face with <kbd>P</kbd> and then corrects and hits <kbd>Y</kbd> to split the face.

I am not familiar with this <kbd>Y</kbd> command and don't really understand what he does and why he does this. I understand that this command copies the face and also deletes the original face ? But the face remains part of the original mesh, is that correct ? But why does he do this ?

And I believe after that he deletes the original face

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Y</kbd> just splits the selected face (separates but stay in the mesh of the object).

He did that because he wants the window to be able to move on side (to be opened or not).

Previously, he did separate effectively from the mesh using <kbd>P</kbd>. But as this separated face is deleted after that, I think this is not what he wanted to obtain (a mistake surely).